# getting the orange from specific index from an array

Tags: ruby

```
class OrangeTree
  def initialize(age = 0, height = 0)
    @age = age
    @height = height
    @count = []
  end

  def aging
    until @age > 10
      screening_array = Array.new
      i = @age + 3
      i.times do
        screening_array << Orange.new
      end
      @age += 1
    end
    screening_array.each_with_index do |orange, index|
      @count << orange if index.even?
    end
    p @count
  end
end

class Orange
  attr_accessor :diameter
  # Initializes a new Orange with diameter +diameter+
  def initialize(diameter = rand(4) + 1)
    @diameter = diameter
  end
end

tree = OrangeTree.new
tree.aging
```

I am trying to fill in the @count with orange that have index 3 and above.. the closest that I can get is to get the orange with even index.. how can I modify this?

Comment: I just did it for you, but please, for the sake of everyone's sanity (including your own) format your code nicely next time! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can inline the comparison you're trying to make:

```
screening_array.each_with_index do |orange, index|
  @count << orange if index > 3
end
```